# Подскажите пожалуйста почему ссылки в html документе не работают, может это ли связано с js?

Tags: javascript, html

вот код html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index2.html" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <script src="js/app.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="logo__menu__basket">
      <div class="logo">
        <img src="images/Untitled.png" alt="" />
      </div>
      <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          
            <li><a href="index2.html">Товары</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Оплата</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Доставка</a></li>
            <li><a href="">О качестве</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Как сделать заказ</a></li>
          
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="social">
        <a class="social-vk" href="https://vk.com/idendy2099"
          ><img src="images/Untitled.png" alt="" height="50px"
        /></a>
        <a class="social-vs" href="https://vk.com/idendy2099"
          ><img src="images/Untitled.png" alt="" height="50px"
        /></a>
      </div>

      <div class="basket-button">
        <img src="images/basket.jpg" alt="" height="50px" />
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <section class="gallery">
        <div class="frame">
          <div class="frame__content">
            <h2><b>СТИЛЬ ЖИЗНИ</b></h2>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame">
          <div class="frame__content">
            <div
              class="frame-media frame-media_left"
              style="background-image: url(images/1.png)"
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame frame_bg">
          <div class="frame__content">
            <video
              class="frame-media frame-media_right"
              src="media/1.mp4"  autoplay  loop  muted></video>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame"></div>

        <div class="frame">
          <div class="frame__content text-right">
            <h3>Не будьте как все!</h3>
            <p>
              Кастомизированная одежда и аксессуары с ручной росписью. Готовые
              работы и уникальные на заказ.
            </p>
            <button>Хочу свой рисунок</button>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame frame_bg">
          <div class="frame__content">
            <div
              class="frame-media frame-media_left"
              style="background-image: url(images/2.png)"
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame"></div>

        <div class="frame frame_bg">
          <div class="frame__content">
            <div
              class="frame-media frame-media_right"
              style="background-image: url(images/3.png)"
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame"></div>

        <div class="frame">
          <div class="frame__content text-left">
            <h3>Кастом уличной одежды в стиле ArtCalligraf</h3>
            <p>
              Если нужно красиво, выразительно и не банально, то это к нам,
              выбирайте. Если хотите мерчи со своими артами, то пишите нам,
              звоните, будем рады!
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame frame_bg">
          <div class="frame__content">
            <div
              class="frame-media frame-media_right"
              style="background-image: url(images/4.jpg)"
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame">
          <div class="frame__content">
            <video
              class="frame-media frame-media_left"
              src="media/2.mp4"  autoplay  loop  muted></video>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame"></div>
        <div class="frame"></div>

        <div class="frame frame_bg">
          <div class="frame__content">
            <div
              class="frame-media frame-media_right"
              style="background-image: url(images/5.jpg)"
            ></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame frame_bg">
          <div class="frame__content">
            <video
              class="frame-media"
              src="media/3.mp4" autoplay   loop    muted></video>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="frame"></div>
        <div class="frame"></div>

        <div class="frame">
          <div class="frame__content"><h5>© IkiGai</h5></div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
 

это код js

    let zSpacing = -1000,
            lastPos = zSpacing / 5,
            $frames = document.getElementsByClassName('frame'),
            frames = Array.from($frames),
            zVals = []
    
    window.onscroll = function() {
    
        let top = document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                delta = lastPos - top
    
        lastPos = top
    
        frames.forEach(function(n, i) {
            zVals.push((i * zSpacing) + zSpacing)
            zVals[i] += delta * -5.5
            let frame = frames[i],
                    transform = `translateZ(${zVals[i]}px)`,
                    opacity = zVals[i] < Math.abs(zSpacing) / 1.8 ? 1 : 0
            frame.setAttribute('style', `transform: ${transform}; opacity: ${opacity}`)
        })
    
    }

window.scrollTo(0, 1)
```

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="index2.html" /> - вы серьезно? Что касается "не работают", то у вас ref="" пустые - куда должна вести эта ссылка?

Comment: Если речь идет про ссылки на меню (оплата, доставка, о качестве, контакты, как сделать заказ), то они и не будут у Вас работать, т.к. в обязательном атрибуте href Вы не указали пути к файлам. Что касается тега  link, то слеша (/) в конце быть не должно.

Comment: Также в тегах `<meta>` и `<img>` слеша (/) в конце быть не должно

Comment: @darinkapoznyak, теги которые не имеют закрывающегося тега (`<img>`, `,<meta>`, `<link>`) могут содержать слеш в конце, стандарт HTML этого не запрещает делать, а вот XHTML наоборот, обязует это делать.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href="index2.html">Товары</a></li>
<li><a href="">Оплата</a></li>
<li><a href="">Доставка</a></li>
<li><a href="">О качестве</a></li>
<li><a href="">Контакты</a></li>
<li><a href="">Как сделать заказ</a></li>
```

В первой ссылке есть указанный html файл, на который при её активации произойдёт перенаправление страницы, а у остальных пустой атрибут href, он как раз таки и указывает, куда будет вести ссылка. Если же тебе нужно на время отладки оставить эти ссылки пустыми, то советую в атрибут href вставлять решётку (#), это своеобразная пустышка, которая приказывает ссылке никуда не перенаправлять текущую страницу.

```
<li><a href="index2.html">Товары</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Оплата</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Доставка</a></li>
<li><a href="#">О качестве</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Как сделать заказ</a></li>
```

Позже, значение можно изменить, вставив в атрибут ссылки то, на что она должна ссылаться. Ничего от этого не сломается, а в JS коде ссылки никак не затронуты, этот скрипт нацелен на что-то визуальное, чтобы глазу приятно было видеть страницу, не более.

Comment: У меня немного другая проблема, у меня сами ссылки не кликаются, даже та, которая введет на страницу html и соответственно ваш варина тоже не работает. Может это тогда связано с css?

Comment: Попробуй удалить эту строчку из head
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index2.html" />
 она *не* подключает к этой странице другой html документ - Это так не работает, и в этом нету нужды. Потому, его можно единый раз упомянуть только как значение атрибута href у одной из ссылок. В экспериментальных целях попробуй в href любой из ссылок вставить этот, или любой другой адрес https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starbucks.
Если не помогло, пиши, дальше будем разбираться